# Is there an example on how to use the API access in Bluemix SSO Cloud Directory?

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I have the Bluemix SSO Cloud Directory set up and bound to my app. Now I can secure my endpoints and tested them in a web browser. However, I need a way to access my endpoints thru REST API calls.  I tried to figure out a way to do so. So far I use the OAuth Token Endpoint Url to retrieve the access token using the grant_type=client_credentials, client_id and client_secret from the Cloud Directory admin UI in Bluemix. However, when I tried to use the access token to reach to my endpoint in Postman by way of supplying a header "Authorization: Bearer {access_token_value}", I got a piece of script back that looks like it's for web browser.

My question is: Does anybody have an example on how to make API access calls once my endpoints are secured by Bluemix SSO? If not, does anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for API driven login flows which are not supported at this time. At the moment we are Browser SSO only.

Comment: Then why do i see the API access info available to me thru the Bluemix SSO dashboard UI?